# "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1" when using mixChannels function (opencv)

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

im trying develop app with Android JNI and OpenCV, and got an terrible error: libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xfffffffc in tid 28694.

Im following [this article](http://answers.opencv.org/question/75510/how-to-make-auto-adjustmentsbrightness-and-contrast-for-image-android-opencv-image-correction/) to implement that algorithm, when i run it on Visual studio 2015, it work fine. But when i try implement it on Android JNI, it got below error.

Here is my code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_noah_demojniexp_MainActivity_autofix(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jlong matAddr,
                                          jlong dstAddr, jfloat clipHistPercent) {
Mat &src = *((Mat *) matAddr);
Mat &dst = *((Mat *) dstAddr);

CV_Assert(clipHistPercent >= 0);
CV_Assert((src.type() == CV_8UC1) || (src.type() == CV_8UC3) || (src.type() == CV_8UC4));

int histSize = 256;
float alpha, beta;
double minGray = 0, maxGray = 0;

//to calculate grayscale histogram
Mat gray;
if (src.type() == CV_8UC1) gray = src;
else if (src.type() == CV_8UC3) cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
else if (src.type() == CV_8UC4) cvtColor(src, gray, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
if (clipHistPercent == 0)
{
    // keep full available range
    minMaxLoc(gray, &minGray, &maxGray);
}
else
{
    Mat hist; //the grayscale histogram

    float range[] = { 0, 256 };
    const float* histRange = { range };
    bool uniform = true;
    bool accumulate = false;
    calcHist(&gray, 1, 0, Mat (), hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);

    // calculate cumulative distribution from the histogram
    std::vector<float> accumulator(histSize);
    accumulator[0] = hist.at<float>(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < histSize; i++)
    {
        accumulator[i] = accumulator[i - 1] + hist.at<float>(i);
    }

    // locate points that cuts at required value
    float max = accumulator.back();
    clipHistPercent *= (max / 100.0); //make percent as absolute
    clipHistPercent /= 2.0; // left and right wings
    // locate left cut
    minGray = 0;
    while (accumulator[minGray] < clipHistPercent)
        minGray++;

    // locate right cut
    maxGray = histSize - 1;
    while (accumulator[maxGray] >= (max - clipHistPercent))
        maxGray--;
}

// current range
float inputRange = maxGray - minGray;

alpha = (histSize - 1) / inputRange;   // alpha expands current range to histsize range
beta = -minGray * alpha;             // beta shifts current range so that minGray will go to 0

// Apply brightness and contrast normalization
// convertTo operates with saurate_cast
src.convertTo(dst, -1, alpha, beta);

// restore alpha channel from source
if (dst.type() == CV_8UC4)
{
    int from_to[] = { 3, 3};
    mixChannels(&src, 4, &dst,1, from_to, 1);
}
return;

}
}
```

I created a class extends org.opencv.core.Mat

```
public class SMat extends Mat {
public void autofix(Mat m,float clip){
    MainActivity.native_autofix(nativeObj,m.nativeObj,clip);
}
}
```

And use it in mainactivity

```
Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.s3);
SMat mat1 = new SMat();
SMat mat2 = new SMat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bm1,mat1);
mat1.autofix(mat2,5);
Bitmap bm2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1);
Utils.matToBitmap(mat1,bm2);
iv2.setImageBitmap(bm2);
```

And here is the error
[image]

When debugging, i find out that the mixChannels function is the reason, if comment it, everything will be okay. I have no idea why it wrong. Pls help! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a MVCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just change the second parameter to 1 because the source Mat just contains one Mat. :D

Answer (score 0):

Source and destination matrices must have the same size and the same depth.

you can clone the size of destination matrix from source matrix like

Mat dst=src.clone();

In the destination field it have same size and depth of original image before pass this to mixChannels function

Comment: I tried as you said but it still give error :(
http://imgur.com/a/ZnKMW